# How to replace symbols in string:

Tags: python, string, list, file, python-re

I have a next code and next files:

```
import re
        
with open("forbidden_words.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as stop, open(f'{input()}', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    stop_words = stop.readline().split(" ")
    text_file = file.readline()
    for i in stop_words:
        text_file = re.sub(i, '*'*len(i), text_file, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    print(text_file)
```

forbidden_words.txt:

```
warning priority candidate leadership recording judgment law responsibility efficiency advertising imagination department maintenance poet village situation description consequence addition context studio funeral depression entertainment artisan recognition customer understanding writer significance manufacturer administration examination grocery quality sample agency trainer possibility association attention performance childhood refrigerator scene hearing wealth development distribution success delivery presentation relationship grandmother confusion chocolate feedback combination midnight aspect drawer negotiation disease internet speech blood temperature decision baseball recommendation contribution boyfriend introduction historian variety explanation replacement control member operation arrival reading preparation celebration computer painting affair tongue perspective environment communication supermarket construction county establishment inflation engine revolution reality variation engineering application event requirement signature safety history transportation appointment problem interaction conversation information gene improvement politics protection indication proposal personality organization opportunity independence soup leader dealer society teaching language memory height sympathy revenue coffee satisfaction pollution tea preference hello email python exam wor
```

data.txt

```
boyfriEND It for have kind, green lesser them doesn him created his moved fruit had.
For whose moved years firmament green image dominion feedback let whales third rule signs midnightblessed light sixth from form for said female land midst and, the likeness.
Fruit evening night for so you called place likeness. Heaven greater to unto said seas female fourth evening dominion which bring they Second.
Two two have.
Heavenmember called fruit form whales saying heaven living firmament unto moved fill appear their.
Form life female, dominion second air won. Cant day.
Morning male to sixth heaven subdue femaleoperation likeness moveth give rule.
hello hearing and wealth. Tooday we development and distribuTIONsucce. The delivery club is the best.
We create PRESENTATION and relationshipwithgrandmother. Please not be confusion, and eatchocolate.
```

data_2.txt

```
replacementcontrol MembeR operation    arrival reading preparationcelebration computer.
painting affair tonguePerspect.nvironment proposal......personality!!!!! organization=====
pollution teaPreferencE hello emai python exam wor
```

data_3.txt

```
DEVELOPMENT distributionsuccess delivery presentation relationship. Grandmother     confusio  chocolate and feedbackCombination.
historian and math variety explanation...... python PYTHON PyToN
```

And I have the following problem: my code does not replace everything that needs to be replaced, what should I replace in my code to fix it?

Comment: `readline()` reads a single line.

Comment: You should include examples of the output and the expected output. What does it replace, and what does it not replace?

Comment: Use `file.read()`. You might also want to use: `text_file = re.sub(fr'\b{i}\b', '*'*len(i), text_file, flags=re.IGNORECASE)` so you don't change a word like 'inlaw'.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("forbidden_words.txt", encoding="utf-8") as file, open(input()) as infile:
    text = infile.read()
    for f in file.read().strip("\n").split():
        pos = text.lower().find(f)
        while pos > -1:
            text = text[:pos] + "*" * len(f) + text[pos+len(f):]
            pos = text.lower().find(f)
print(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You used the readline command when you need to use readlines commend.

Also, I recommend you try using more meaningful names, it is the best practice(read this article to understand why https://towardsdatascience.com/data-scientists-your-variable-names-are-awful-heres-how-to-fix-them-89053d2855be)

for example, your code should look more like that:

```
with open("forbidden_words.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as forbidden_file, open(f'{input()}', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as input_file:
    forbidden_words = forbidden_file.readline().split(" ")
    text_file = input_file.readline()
    for forbidden_word in forbidden_words:
        text_file = re.sub(forbidden_word, '*'*len(i), text_file, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    print(text_file)
```